# Match regex dont seperate uppercase or not uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, count, match, cpu-word

I have been searching on the site, but could not find an answer to my problem. I have a JavaScript regex pattern that matches some words and numbers. If I use a keyword "gemstone" and my input string has "Gemstone" in it, no match is found due to the fact that the word starts with an uppercase letter. How can I make the regex stop caring if a word contains uppercase letters? My current code:

```
var count =  (countDescription.match(new RegExp('(\\b)('+ u + ')(\\b)', 'g')) || []).length;
```

Comment: add 'i' modifier - case insensitive search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `i` option:

```
var count =  (countDescription.match(new RegExp('(\\b)('+ u + ')(\\b)', 'gi')) || []).length;
```